# Is it possible to perform an upsert that requires filtering in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the following statement to do an upsert w/ filtering. That is, can I first try to update with a where clause, if it fails, then insert, rather than the other way around?  I would like to do this in Postgres.

> INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE

I did see this, but it is definitely a bit more complicated
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/idiomatic-way-to-implement-upsert-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That is, can I first try to update with a where clause, if it fails, then insert, rather than the other way around?

It's unclear why you would want to do this.

The purpose of UPSERT is to ensure that the database contains exactly one row with a given key and with a given set of other column values.  Postgres tries INSERT first because INSERT will fail when the key conflicts with a duplicate row (so that it can fall back to updating the conflicting row instead of raising an exception).  UPDATE will not fail if the WHERE clause matches nothing.  It will [successfully update zero rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.7).  UPDATE can fail if you violate a constraint (e.g. a CHECK or NOT NULL constraint), but it won't fail just because you didn't match any rows.

And, on the other hand, if your UPDATE would change an existing row, then your INSERT would necessarily fail with a uniqueness violation (because the row exists).  So trying the INSERT first doesn't actually change the result in this case.

It is possible to hang a condition on PostgreSQL's UPSERT, with syntax of the form [`INSERT... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE... WHERE...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).  This will:

1. Insert the rows you provide.
2. For each conflict with an existing row, evaluate the WHERE condition for that row.
3. If the WHERE condition is satisfied, update the existing row, otherwise do nothing with it.

I believe this is functionally equivalent to what you are asking for, because:

1. If the row does not exist, Postgres will INSERT it. UPDATE wouldn't have affected it, so your method would have had to fall back to INSERTing it anyway.
2. If the row exists, but does not match the WHERE clause, then Postgres will do nothing.  I think your method would either do nothing or fail with a uniqueness constraint after trying to INSERT it, but perhaps you had something else in mind for this case.
3. If the row exists and matches the WHERE clause, both Postgres and your method will do an UPDATE on that row.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, what you said here makes sense.  I'll continue to use the `insert ... on conflict do...where` syntax, but I realized that I need to add some constraints such as the `unique` constraint on a few colums on my table so that they can effectively be made into keys (w/o making them into primary keys, which was what I was trying to avoid).